# Equivalent tool to MODO’s Falloff

Tags: modeling

is there a tool in Blender or add-on that provides similar features to MODO’s falloff tool? For example I have a cube that I have added several edge loops and then scaled on the Y axis. I want to now curve the cube creating an insect like shape. In MODO I would apply a linear falloff and then rotate the cube, giving me a nice curve. I tried with the proportional editing option but I do not get the same level of success I get with the MODO tool. Am I just miss-using the proportional editing feature or there is a more suitable way.

Image below shows the falloff tool in Modo and the effect I would like to create in Blender.

[image: Modo Falloff]

Thanks !

Comment: There are multiple modes to the proportional edit tool, among which is a linear fall of. You can change the fall off next to where you activate proportional editing - in the bottom of the 3D View

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of the desired effect?

Comment: Thank you @someonewithpc I will give that go and see if I can get what I'm after.

Comment: Hi @zeffii I've added an image from Modo with the desired affect and the falloff tool still active. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an addon that provides similar functionality to what you described called Mira Tools by Paul Geraskin, here is a [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eon0h77LO6o) demonstrating how it works. You can get the addon from [Github](https://github.com/mifth/mifthtools)